# Url rewriting in php for specific values only

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a link

```
http://sonibazar.in/profile.php?id=1
```

I want to redirect it to

```
http://sonibazar.in/username
```

Same as above
I have another different link

```
http://sonibazar.in/profile.php?id=2
```

want to redirect it to

```
http://sonibazar.in/anotherusername
```

All this is in profile.php but I want to use them using different addresses and different values.

It's something like Facebook username assigning... I want to create usernames for users in my website. so they can land to their profile directly (without logging in)...

Comment: Are the users stored in a database?

Comment: Yes, Users are stored in database but not the username...

Answer (score 0):

**URL**

> http://domain.com/profile.php?id=1
>
> to
>
> http://domain.com/kristories

**profile.php**

```
$user = ''; // From database

if($_GET['id'] == $user){
    echo "hi ".$user->name.", You're Rock!";
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: can we force redirect `http://domain.com/profile.php?id=1` to `http://domain.com/kristories` when user opens  `http://domain.com/profile.php?id=1`

Comment: Yes. You can do it via `.htaccess` or `PHP`.

Comment: I know but how ? I don't have much knowledge of .htaccess, can you give an example ?